# how to generate dhcp client id

Tags: linux, templates, unix, networking, dhcp

When [isc dhcpd](https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp)
used in ddns mode, it generates a hashid for every client that requests an ip address. Then dhcpd places this hashid near close to A record of client in DNS server.

Hash id: it's an md5 of client id.
While reading an [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsext-dhcid-rr-13#page-6) 
I was trying to understand how I can generate this hashid by myself, but I can't. I need some examples, because I don't know which type of data uses dhcpd server when generate all id types.
Can someone please give some examples how can I do this, on any language you like?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not an RFC, it is a draft, and it expired six years ago.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to emulate the ISC DHCP id generation or just need to generate an arbitrary unique id for DHCP clients?

Comment: Hi! I want to generate unique id in the way just like isc dhcpd it does.